# iOS Swift - Properties not updating after preparing for segue

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, segue

I am trying to pass a news ID of type string to the second VC and load the object based on it from Realm. When I debugged, I found that the prepare for segue is correctly setting the detailNewsVC.newsID to the primary key of my news item but the second VC is not receiving it. Any help on this?

Checks I have made:

1. Made sure that the detail VC identifier is correct
2. detailNewsVC.newsID in VC 1 is correctly setting the news ID .. This is to make sure that realm is correctly sending the newsID and it is working fine.
3. Changed the viewDidLoad in VC 2 to viewWillLoad..Just to make sure that second vc is not loaded before for any reason but no luck on that.
4. Restarted xcode
5. Replaced newsID in VC 2 with an actual news primary key and it's correctly pulling the related news. I think the culprit is that the VC2 property: newsID is not updating when prepare for segue is called.

First VC code for prep for segue:

```
extension HomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifier.gotodetail.rawValue, let sendNewsID = sender as? String {

        let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController

        let detailNewsVC = navVC?.viewControllers.first as! DetailNewsVC

        detailNewsVC.newsID = sendNewsID
        print("Detail News ID = \(detailNewsVC.newsID)")
    }


}

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt     indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let newsID = newsArray[indexPath.row].newsId

    performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.gotodetail.rawValue, sender: newsID)

}



}
```

Second VC Code:

```
class DetailNewsVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet private weak var newsTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet private weak var newsDescription: UILabel!

var newsID = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let realm = try! Realm()

    print("News ID: \(newsID)")
    guard let news = realm.object(ofType: News.self, forPrimaryKey: newsID as AnyObject) else {
        print("Cannot load news")
        return
    }

    print(news)

    newsTitle.text = news.newsTitle

    if let url = URL(string: news.urlToImage), let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url) {

        newsImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

    }

    newsDescription.text = news.newsDescription

}


}
```

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code. Show _code_. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, also: you are logging a lot in that code. Good idea. Show _us_ the results of that logging, please.

Comment: Okay. Can't share the code fully unfortunately. I can print out the results if that helps?

First VC - 

Detail News ID = 3401CF5C-FCC6-4642-B7D8-31D47C7CC86B
Second VC 

News ID:

This newsID is coming empty.

Comment: Post the code that you've shown pictures of rather than images. Since you've shown images of that code, you should at least be able to post THAT code. Same with the results. Post that as text, not as images. We can't search images, we can't copy text from images and suggest changes, etc.

Comment: Just updated. Please check

Comment: Do not post links to code either. Post your code and the logging results right here in the question! This is not hard!

Comment: OK @Revanth the next thing I suggest is that you debug. Put a breakpoint on the line in `prepare` that _sets_ the second VC's `newsID` and put a breakpoint on the line in the second VC's `viewDidLoad` that _gets_ the second VC's `newsID` and see what's happening and in what order.

Comment: Also in the log you are getting a very important message saying "The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values." _You need to fix that issue!_ It isn't just telling you that for fun. It's serious.

Comment: Hi Matt- The 1st breakpoint sets the 2nd VC newsID and the second breakpoint refers back to the empty newsID property in VC2 again.

Comment: Not sure if I'm on the right track, but I would be checking to make sure the the controller assigned to `detailNewsVC` in VC1 is actually the `DetailNewsVC' instance you are expecting it to be. Setting a value and then finding it blank in the second controller suggests they are not the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Move your prepare function out of the extension and put it in HomeVC. According to Apple's Swift Guide extensions cannot override existing functionality.

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

[Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell in which order UIKit calls the `UIViewController` methods, but it might be possible that `viewDidLoad` is getting called before you get the chance to set the value of `newsID`.

The following might be overkill, but it'll guarantee the views will be updated during `viewDidLoad`, or otherwise if `newsID` is set after the fact:

```
class DetailNewsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var newsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var newsDescription: UILabel!

    public var newsID = "" {
        didSet {
            updateUIForNews()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUIForNews() 
    }

    private func updateUIForNews() {
        guard !newsID.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        let realm = try! Realm()

        print("News ID: \(newsID)")
        guard let news = realm.object(ofType: News.self, forPrimaryKey: newsID as AnyObject) else {
            print("Cannot load news")
            return
        }

        print(news)

        newsTitle.text = news.newsTitle

        if let url = URL(string: news.urlToImage), let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url) {

            newsImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

        }

        newsDescription.text = news.newsDescription
    }
}
```